# Scipy Bodgy curve fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have simple survey data collected in the field using an uncalibrated compass. Realising the problem, in the field, bearing were taken comparing a good compass to the uncalibrated compass and the differences recorded in 11 bearings. The plot shows the difference being pretty close to a sin function.
I wish to fit a polynomial (degree 3) to this resulting function to use correcting the survey data using the uncalibrated compass. My curve fitting program produces a poor fitting curve. can anyone see what is wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pylab
correctCompass=\
np.array([134.4,112.6,069.7,051.1,352.5,314.6,218.3,258.2,237.8,186.5,153.7])
errorCompass=\
np.array([131.6,108.9,065.6,047.0,349.8,314.0,284.6,262.7,243.4,189.8,153.2])
# sort compass values
for i in range(0,11):
   for j in range(i+1,11):
       if correctCompass[i] > correctCompass[j]:
          tmp=correctCompass[j]
          correctCompass[j]=correctCompass[i]
          correctCompass[i]=tmp
          tmp=errorCompass[j]
          errorCompass[j]=errorCompass[i]
          errorCompass[i]=tmp

diff = correctCompass - errorCompass + 15.0
height=diff.max() + 16.0
polycoeffs = scipy.polyfit(correctCompass, diff, 3)

# fit the data with a polynomial
yfit = scipy.polyval(polycoeffs,correctCompass)

pylab.plot(correctCompass, diff, 'k.')
pylab.plot(correctCompass, yfit, 'r-')

pylab.axis([0,360,-10.0,height])
pylab.show()
```

Comment: pylab contains numpy, so importing the two is redundant. I would suggest to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and numpy

Answer (score 2):

`polyfit` works fine, the problem is one negative point in `diff` that bring down the fit but that is not shown in your plot as you set the lowest value for the yaxis to -10

```
diff = array([ 19.1,  19.1,  18.7,  17.8,  15.5,  11.7, -51.3,   9.4,  10.5, 15.6,  17.7])
```

If you comment `pylab.axis([0,360,-10.0,height])` you'll see the "problem"

Besides, you can improve and make your code more readable substituting the two nested for loops with the following three lines:

```
sort = np.argsort(correctCompass)
correctCompass = correctCompass[sort]
errorCompass = errorCompass[sort]
```

Comment: Uhhhh just didn't see that. I accidentally transposed 81 to 18 and didn't see the data point error because it was off the plot. Thankyou for the tip about sorting that is a good trick.

Comment: You're welcome. It does happen. As rule: if you have to do something that imply for loops try to: 1) find some solution that does not require `for` (list comprehension, numpy, operations between lists,arrays, ...); 2) if you can't avoid, see if you can avoid nested loops (in this case `itertools` is often your friend)